# In html we use href for navigating to another page. how to perform the same operation in php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I am very beginner in php.I need to know how to fetch the data from the url and pass it to another page using html.

```
http://localhost/userdetails.php?branchId=2
```

This is my url i need to get the value `branchId=2` and pass it to next page `userdetails.2php` what is the syntax for this operation As a beginner am having trouble in doing that.

Comment: You need header location url

Comment: `header('Location: http://localhost/userdetails.php?branchId=2');`

Comment: @divy3993 Its applicable for html?

Comment: What do you mean by applicable for HTML?

Comment: you need to use it inside php tags.and there should not be any output before this.

Comment: Thank you and sorry i didn't get exact syntax tatsy i raised question here

Comment: Duplicate Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getting parameters from url, use `$_GET`. So in `userdetails.php`, use

```
$_GET['branchId'];
```